# Can one use css to loop a flexbox slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built a carousel using flexbox: 
I need it to slide every 3 seconds and repeat the loop
Add previous and next buttons on the sides
Add navigation dots under it. 
Is there a way to do this with css? Or do I need to use jquery? 
This is my carousel code:

```
<section class="section section-logo">
 Logo Carousel
<div class="logo_carousel">
<?php   
    if( have_rows('logos') );
     while( have_rows('logos') ): the_row(); 
        $image = get_sub_field('logo_image');
        $content = get_sub_field('name');
?>
    <span class="logo_slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
    </span>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</section>
```

This is the css:

```
   .section-logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo_carousel {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.logo_carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.logo_slide img {
  width: 195px;
  height: 115px;
}

.logo_slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;               /* added, so it won't shrink  */
  display: flex;                /*  added  */
  align-items: center;          /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;      /*  added animation: slide-it 10s infinite; */
  width: 195px;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.logo_slide:hover .logo_tt {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Also I'm trying to add the navigation icons and the slider arrows with html code after `<div class="logo_carousel">` but it is not showing up. Where should I place this code? 
If I need to use javascript how should I make it slide using javascript?

Comment: Why not use a library like https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/?

Comment: This where you would use Javascript, css is not really a programming language to handle stuff like this. You can use the javascript function `setInterval()` to set an interval time in milliseconds to fire a function to manipulate the styling on the element(s). There's many libraries out there to help you do this, including bootstrap. 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Comment: I'm using sage and if I try and add javascript to the route file the page just reloads again and again.

Comment: Here is an example of pure css slider. But it's not flexbox. Maybe you want it https://codepen.io/drygiel/pen/rtpnE